# Automatic time-zone changer for each user

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, time

I'm running a comment script, and i want to fix the time each post was added in.

While it was posted 19:21 in norway it were posted 20:21 somewhere else.
Something witch also makes a "time since" useless.

Do you understand the issue?

I'm basically i'm looking for a way to change the time to the local area of each user.

Could anyone provide me with a solution for my problem?
I'm currently using php, but i could go for javascript too.

I've seen a website use this code: document.write( GetElapsedTime( 1330160527 ) );
But then again, i have no idea of how i could get each time-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, `new Date().getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 **local time**, that is, based on the browser's time zone. To convert this to the server's time, the server must render the page with its own calculation of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, the you can use Javascript to convert the browser's time to the server's timezone, like this:

```
var serverTime = 1330160527; // Sever's time rendered by PHP
// Calculate time difference, rounding it to nearest half hour.
var timeDifference = Math.round ( (new Date().getTime() - 1330160527) 
         / (30 * 60 * 1000) ) * (30 * 60 * 1000); 

// Later, when we post the time to the server, we adjust by timeDifference
var localTime = (new Date()).setTime(new Date().getTime() - timeDifference);
```

Note that we round the time difference (in milliseconds) to the nearest half-hour because two different timezones must be at least half an hour apart, but never a smaller fraction of an hour.

Comment: It is likely simplest is to do everything in UTC and only worry about timezone when displaying the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the users timezone information? If you do, you can do it in php, assuming you save the posted time in unix timestamp. If not, then you will have to do it using javascript.

```
$time = time(); // Current time in unix timestamp
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');  // Desired timezone

$datetime = new DateTime(); 
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone); 
$datetime->setTimestamp($time);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send a UTC timestamp to the client (i.e. milliseconds since 00:00 on 1/1/1970 or 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z), you can convert it to a local time in javascript using:

```
// Just to get local timezone offset
var tmp = new Date();

// Adjust timestamp to local time and create a local date object
var localTime = new Date(timestamp - tmp.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4);
```

The javascript timezone offset is returned as minutes to add to a local time to get UTC, so for a timezone of UTC+10 it's -600. You can return an equivalent timestamp by reversing the operation:

```
var tmp = new Date();
var UTCtimestamp = tmp + tmp.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4
```

Of course that all depends on the local machine having its clock set accurately.